# Summation With Binomial Coefficient

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I am wondering how to estimate the following summation.

For $p \ge 0$,

$$
\sum_{i=0}^n \binom{2n}{i} (-1)^i (n-i)^p.
$$

When $p$ is a fixed integer this seems easy to do. But what if $p$ is a general real number? 
I performed some numerical simulation and it seems this summation equals zero iff p is even. Can we give some lower bound to this summation, in general?

Update: the lower bound of the summation should be i=0, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Welcome to the site ! If $p=2$ the result is $-n^2$, not $0$.

Comment: Maybe the sum is supposed to go up to $2n$?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Now the expression is updated and the lower bound of the summation should be 0.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot post this as comment: a few graphs for $n=20$ with horizontal axis representing values of $p$.

[image]

Here is the part for $8<p<10$:

[image]

...and for $10<p<12$:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the graphs! These graphs again confirm my conjecture that this summation is zero iff p is even.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the question asked about $p$ an even integer we evaluate

$$S_{n,p} = \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-q)^p.$$

Note that

$$\sum_{q=n}^{2n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-q)^p
= \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n\choose n+q} (-1)^{n+q} (-q)^p
\\ = \sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n\choose 2n-q} (-1)^q (q-n)^p.$$

With $p$ even this is

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-q)^p.$$

Since the  duplicate term for  $q=n$ from the  lower and upper  sum is
zero we thus have

$$2S_{n,p} = \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q (n-q)^p
\\ = p! [z^p] \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q
\exp((n-q)z)
\\ = p! [z^p] \exp(nz) \sum_{q=0}^{2n} {2n\choose q} (-1)^q
\exp(-qz)
\\ = p! [z^p] \exp(nz) (1-\exp(-z))^{2n}.$$

Since $1-\exp(-z) =  z + \cdots$ and hence  $(1-\exp(z))^{2n} = z^{2n}
+\cdots$ this  is zero when $p\lt  2n.$ In other words,  $S_{n,p} = 0$
when $p$ is even and $2n\gt p.$ We also find that for $p=2n$ the value
is

$$\frac{1}{2} (2n)! [z^{2n}] \exp(nz) (1-\exp(-z))^{2n}
= \frac{1}{2} (2n)! [z^0] \exp(nz) = \frac{1}{2} (2n)!.$$

Comment: Thanks! A question though. It seems this method heavily relies on the symmetry when p is even. For general p can we still calculate the generating function? I guess the difficulty comes from the upper bound of the summation. Also what can we say for real p?